# SQLite 3 insert. Database is not changed even if insert doesn't fail

Tags: ios, sqlite

after an update , my sqlite database, is not changed.
All seems fine, no error message and I'm able to print out

```
   int rows= sqlite3_changes(database); 
    NSLog(@"rows %d" , rows);
```

the number of rows updated. Nevertheless if I read the table (from sqlite console pointing to the Library folder where I copied the file. But even if I read it with a new objective-c method)
after updating it is like no update was run.

Here is my full method. I've tried even a sql insert but with the same problem.
Have you got any idea about what I could try or what is the problem?

Thanks.

```
   -(void)saveBookmark:(FfBookmark *) bookmark {

int resconn = sqlite3_open([pathDB UTF8String], &database);

if (resconn == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSString * query = @"update  bookmarks set position=?  ";
    const char * sqlStatement = [query UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt * compiledStatement;

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1 , &compiledStatement,   NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        sqlite3_bind_int(compiledStatement, 1, bookmark.position);



    } 

    if (!sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {

        NSLog(@"Error @%" , sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    int rows= sqlite3_changes(database);

    NSLog(@"rows %d" , rows);


sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);


}


sqlite3_close(database);

  }
```

Comment: Won't this always be false? `(!sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)`

Comment: Yes @HotLicks , I couldn't see that. Thanks. It says the database is locked. I have to figure out why.                                                              `if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE) {
   
   NSLog(@"DONE");
  } else {
            NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));}  `

Comment: Could you load it from a plist, manipulate it programmatically, then save it back to that plist?